# Is there a way to use massivejs and use dynamic variable for table name to create table and select table?

Tags: postgresql, massivejs

I have setup a postgreSQL access through a node server using express and massive, but I cannot find a way to build new tables with dynamic table names or select a table dynamically using massive. Any direction would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create dynamic SQL through script files. Massive does exactly what you're intending internally when you [create document tables](https://github.com/dmfay/massive-js/blob/master/lib/scripts/document-table.sql).
2. Tables (and other database objects) are properties on the `db` object so you can use bracket accessor syntax with a variable, viz. `await db[thisOrThatTableName].find(...)`.